# Angular2/Typescript: How to convert a Javascript/Typescript Date to a String representation of C# DateTime client side

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

i'm busy with an Angular2/Typescript project where I need to send a date to a C# backend...  i've read up a lot but all I can find by googling is how to convert the date on the backend...  The last thing I tried was the toIsoString() javascript method but that didn't work either even though it looked correct in the console...  Any idea how I can go about this?

Comment: The fact is that your date is automatically converted when you're trying to send it to your back as a String format, just like a JSON object with key -> value. You can't have the exact same type on a language and in another one. You need to use your backend to convert it, since it's the only one able to translate the incoming string into a proper C# Date

Comment: You should use C# rather to convert JSON string /Object to DateTime format if required..

Comment: I don't need the exact same type just a string which I can then assign to the DateTime type, is that possible at all?

Comment: Please provide your C# code. You will probably have to use `DateTIme.ParseExact` with the `"o"` format, but nobody can tell for sure without the code.

Comment: please share your code to which we could be able to answer you.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I managed to get it to work at the end...

```
this.invoice.InvoiceDate = "/Date(" + new Date(invoice.InvoiceDate).toISOString() + ")/";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <reference path="definition/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

$('document').ready(function(){
    let myDate: Date = new Date();
    let dateString = myDate.toISOString();
    console.log(dateString);
});
```

output will be `2017-02-13T13:08:07.966Z` what you should interpret in c#

perhaps the problem is to interpret this string with c#, there i cant help